# Is "I >am having< a code which ... " acceptable?

Tags: tense, verb-forms, present-continuous

On StackOverflow I often see this:

> **I’m having a code which** (*does such and such, followed by a fragment of code*)

Is *I am having a code* grammatically correct? I think it is incorrect, and that it should be, *I have some code*, but I continue to see it more and more frequently.

Is it grammatically correct, or is it a common error? If it is correct, why?

Comment: In what context do you hear this?

Comment: @Squazic Forms like this appear quite frequently on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22i+am+having+a%22).

Comment: As in, can you give some more context like examples and such?

Comment: Personally I would write "I have this piece (bit) of code" or "I have this code".

Comment: I've taken the liberty of incorporating an SO example into your question - something concrete like this provides context which will avoid confusion. Also, it's conventional in discussion of language to *italicize* examples being discussed rather than to enclose them in quotes; certainly you don't need both.

Comment: This is *two* questions, though you may not realize it. The first is the proper use of "I am having a NNN", the present progressive of *have*. The second is which determiner is the correct one to use with the noun *code*.

Comment: @ctype.h Search for the whole phrase; you're right, it is [shockingly common](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22i+am+having+a+code%22).

Comment: It is fine to say "I'm having a code" in the sense of "I am having a swim", i.e. enjoying an activity (in this case coding), but the example you give is not that usage and appears wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"I am having a code" doesn't make sense, whereas "I have some code" does make sense.

"A code" might be used for, say, an identification code, which is unique, but "code" as used here more likely means "a piece of code" like a script, or a coherent block of computer instructions.

"Am having" implies that something is taking place over a span of (present) time, while "have" implies possession; possession is the more likely meaning here.  "I am having a problem with this code" expresses a logical situation where the "am having" construction makes sense.

Comment: I think "a code" is sometimes used by people who have difficulty with uncountable nouns, such as native speakers of Japanese.

Comment: "I'm having a code" is what a computer virus might say... nom nom nom...